# extracting factors from row in data frame

Tags: r, reshape

I'm dealing with a ragged dataframe that contains a column of timepoints in the first column, a list of serial numbers in the first row, and the actual inventory data (# of items) in the rest of the dataframe.

```
> mydf
    V1             V2             V3             V4             V5
1 month item_serial123 item_serial234 item_serial345 item_serial456
2     0            234            120            302            500
3     1            344            125            350            450
4     2            235            129            400            300
5     3            453            145            450            330
6     4            200            130            500            200
7     5            201                           501               
8     6                                          504            202
```

I'm trying to format the data such that I have a 'long' list such that I can run an analysis on each item's serial number.  I can discard the non-numeric data from my list and make sure the data is imported as character objects by setting the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` flag in `read.table`, then transforming mydf into a data matrix:

```
> mydf.new<-data.matrix(mydf)
Warning in data.matrix(mydf) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(mydf) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(mydf) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(mydf) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(mydf) : NAs introduced by coercion
> mydf.new
     V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
[1,] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[2,]  0 234 120 302 500
[3,]  1 344 125 350 450
[4,]  2 235 129 400 300
[5,]  3 453 145 450 330
[6,]  4 200 130 500 200
[7,]  5 201  NA 501  NA
[8,]  6  NA  NA 504 202
```

> 

changing the variable V1 to "time" is trivial.  What i'm really struggling with is how to extract the serial numbers from `mydf[1,2:5]` and assigning them to the appropriate data when I melt/cast `mydf.new`.  What I'd like to wind up with is something like this:

```
   time count serial_number
   0    234 item_serial123
   1    344 item_serial123
   2    235 item_serial123
   3    453 item_serial123
   4    200 item_serial123
   5    201 item_serial123
   6    NA  item_serial123
```

etc. etc.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to use `header=TRUE` when reading the data with `read.table` for R to understand that the first row corresponds to the colnames, then you can apply `data.matrix(mydf)` without warnings

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, then you have a data.frame like this:

```
> df
  month item_serial123 item_serial234 item_serial345 item_serial456
1     0            234            120            302            500
2     1            344            125            350            450
3     2            235            129            400            300
4     3            453            145            450            330
5     4            200            130            500            200
6     5            201             NA            501             NA
7     6             NA             NA            504            202
```

now, you can use `reshape` to get the following:

```
> df_new <- reshape(df, idvar = "month",  varying = list(2:5), 
                    v.names="item_serial", direction = "long",
                    new.row.names=1:(prod(dim(df[,-1]))))
> df_new$time <- factor(df_new$time, labels=names(df)[-1])
> df_new
   month           time item_serial  # you may want to use `colnames`to chance them
1      0 item_serial123         234
2      1 item_serial123         344
3      2 item_serial123         235
4      3 item_serial123         453
5      4 item_serial123         200
6      5 item_serial123         201
7      6 item_serial123          NA
8      0 item_serial234         120
```